# where to use preventDefault(); in jquery to stop submit form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form data to php using jquery. I dont want to submit it  by default. code is working fine. I dont know where to use `event.preventDefault();`

below is my jquery code

```
<script>
 $(function () {
             $("#submit").click(function () {
                var password = $("#password").val();
                var confirmPassword = $("#confirm_password").val();
                var dataString='password='+ password + 'confirmPassword='+ confirmPassword;
                if (password != confirmPassword) {
                    alert("Passwords and Confirm Password Should match.");
                    return false;
                }

                else{

                $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update-password.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(result){
            alert(result)

        }
      });


     }

   });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Note: Don't use `click` events to control form submission. It is bypassed by keyboard form submission! Always use the `submit` event.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, then post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `click` events to control form submission. It is bypassed by keyboard form submission! Always use the `submit` event.

As you are submitting the form via Ajax you can stop the submit immediately with `e.preventDefault()`

e.g.

```
$(function() {
 $("form").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var password = $("#password").val();
   var confirmPassword = $("#confirm_password").val();
   var dataString = 'password=' + password + 'confirmPassword=' + confirmPassword;
   if (password != confirmPassword) {
     alert("Passwords and Confirm Password Should match.");
   } else {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "update-password.php",
       data: dataString,
       success: function(result) {
         alert(result)
       }
     });
   }
 });
});
```

Note: as you are not doing anything special with the submit, you might as well *not* use Ajax unless you needed to. Just conditionally return `true` or `false`.

Returning false is the same as `e.preventDefault()` *and* `e.stopPropagation()`.

e.g.

```
$(function() {
 $("form").submit(function() {
   var password = $("#password").val();
   var confirmPassword = $("#confirm_password").val();
   var dataString = 'password=' + password + 'confirmPassword=' + confirmPassword;
   if (password != confirmPassword) {
     alert("Passwords and Confirm Password Should match.");
     return false
   }
 });
});
```

General advice: Don't use `alert` for interaction with the user. Show validation messages on the page instead.

Comment: hi thank you for e.preventDefault(); did't work for me but i just modified my code i changed the place of  return false. i moved it to after ajax alert, its working as i required. thank you for explanation. accepted